# Ruby Rock, Paper, Scissors

Tags: ruby

Im having an issue with the score updater for this rock, paper, scissors game I have to create for my ruby class. The purpose of this assignment is to have the user input a choice, the computer makes a random choice as well using "rand", and whoever wins the round has a score updated that is displayed at the end of each round. The problem im running into is that the counter only updates using the first if statement. The program works up to the point that it is able to randomly select the computer choice and it saves the users response as well. So all the code is fine up to where the score updater is used. Any assistance would be highly appreciated.

```
human_score = 0.0
comp_score = 0.0

while true

print "Lets play rock,paper,scissors", "\n"
print "Do you choose rock, paper, or scissors?", "\n"
choice = STDIN.gets.chomp
comp = rand(3)
    if comp == 1
        comp_choice = "rock"
    elsif comp == 2
        comp_choice = "paper"
    else
        comp_choice = "scissors"
    end
print "Computer picked: ", comp_choice, "\n"
print "You picked: ", choice, "\n"
    if human_choice = "rock" && comp_choice = "rock"
        comp_score += 0.5
        human_score += 0.5
        print "The result is a tie", "\n"
    elsif human_choice = "rock" && comp_choice = "paper"
        comp_score += 1
        print "Computer wins", "\n"
    elsif human_choice = "rock" && comp_choice = "scissors"
        human_score += 1
        print "You win", "\n"
    elsif human_choice = "paper" && comp_choice = "rock"
        human_score += 1
        print "You win", "\n"
    elsif human_choice = "paper" && comp_choice = "paper"
        comp_score += 0.5
        human_score += 0.5
        print "Its a tie", "\n"
    elsif human_choice = "paper" && comp_choice = "scissors"
        comp_score += 1
        print "Computer wins", "\n"
    elsif human_choice = "scissors" && comp_choice = "rock"
        comp_score += 1
        print "Computer wins"
    elsif human_choice = "scissors" && comp_choice = "paper"
        human_score += 1
        print "You win"
    else human_choice = "scissors" && comp_choice = "scissors"
        human_score += 0.5
        comp_score += 0.5
        print "Its a tie"
    end
print "The computers score is: ", comp_score, "\n"
print "Your score is: ", human_score, "\n"

end
```

Comment: Your `if` statements for comparing choices all use `=`, which is successfully assigning to those variables; change these to `==`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are reassigning the value of your variables instead of checking for equality.

**Your version:**

```
if human_choice = "rock" && comp_choice = "rock"
```

This sets the value of `human_choice` to "rock" and same with `comp_choice`. It will always be true.

**Correct version:**

```
if human_choice == "rock" && comp_choice == "rock"
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, you are assigning the value read from the keyboard to `choice`

```
choice = STDIN.gets.chomp
```

and you are using `human_choice` to validate the cases.

Answer (score 0):

Meditate on this:

```
human_score = 0.0
comp_score = 0.0

while true

  puts "Lets play rock, paper, scissors"
  puts "Do you choose rock, paper, or scissors?"
  human_choice = STDIN.gets.chomp

  comp_choice = %w[scissors rock paper][rand(3)]

  puts "Computer picked: #{ comp_choice }"
  puts "You picked: #{ human_choice }"

  msg = case [human_choice, comp_choice]
  when ['rock', 'rock'], ['paper', 'paper'], ['scissors', 'scissors']
    comp_score += 0.5
    human_score += 0.5
    'The result is a tie'
  when ['rock', 'scissors'], ['paper', 'rock'], ['scissors', 'paper']
    human_score += 1
    'You win'
  when ['paper', 'scissors'], ['scissors', 'rock'], ['rock', 'paper']
    comp_score += 1
    'Computer wins'
  end

  puts msg
  puts "The computer's score is: #{ comp_score }"
  puts "Your score is: #{ human_score }"

end
```

It's written using idiomatic Ruby.